# BottomNavigation GONE

Tags: android, kotlin, bottomnavigationview

I have a bottom navigation that is being created in my Main Activity, however, I want to make it disappear in a fragment. How can I make my bottom navigation disappear?

Class Main Activity

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val controlador by lazy {
        findNavController(R.id.pokemons_activity_nav_host)
    }

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity)
    configNavControler()

}

private fun configNavControler() {
    val navView: BottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.main_activity_bottom_navigation)
    val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager
        .findFragmentById(R.id.pokemons_activity_nav_host) as NavHostFragment
    val navController = navHostFragment.navController

    navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
  }
}
```

Fragment class where I want my bottom navigation not to appear

```
class EntradaFragment : Fragment() {
private val controlador by lazy {
    findNavController()
}
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    return inflater.inflate(
        R.layout.entrada,
        container,
        false
    )

}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    botao_entrar.setOnClickListener {
        val direcao = EntradaFragmentDirections.acaoEntradaParaListaPokemons()
        controlador.navigate(direcao)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `topDestinationIds` property contains ids of your main fragments. When the navigation is changed, the nav controller's listener is called, there you change the visibility of your bottom navigation view.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val controlador by lazy {
        findNavController(R.id.pokemons_activity_nav_host)
    }

    private val topDestinationIds = setOf(
        R.id.firstFragment,
        R.id.secondFragment,
        R.id.thirdFragment
    )

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity)
    configNavControler()

}

private fun configNavControler() {
    val navView: BottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.main_activity_bottom_navigation)
    val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager
        .findFragmentById(R.id.pokemons_activity_nav_host) as NavHostFragment
    val navController = navHostFragment.navController

    navView.setupWithNavController(navController)

    navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { _, destination, _ ->
        if (destination.id !in topDestinationIds) {
            navView.visibility = View.GONE
        } else {
            navView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: I added this code in the "Main Activity" but it didn't take away the visibility. What should I change the most to remove visibility? Do I have to work on the "Entrada Fragment"?

Comment: Did you exactly paste this code? You have to replace those fake `topDestinationIds` with the id of `EntradaFragment` which the id defined in your nav graph. I don't know how  your code looks like so I can't say what you have to do, but here the [documentation about this](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#listen_for_navigation_events)

Comment: I put the "R.id.entrada_graph" which is the id of my fragment of the xml of nav_graph. I don't know if it's the correct one

Comment: You should put an id (`yourFragmentId`) of your fragment in the XML file, not a nav graph id.
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/yourFragmentId"

Answer (score 0):

At first access your `BottommNavigationView` from your fragment like this:

```
var nav = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.main_activity_bottom_navigation)
```

and then you can hide it like this:

```
nav.visibility = View.GONE
```

Comment: That first part that you posted I do in "Entrada Fragment"? I'm not able to apply this there

Comment: you have several possible solutions to do this. You can create callbacks, you can hide bottomNavigationView before show your fragment, etc.